# Why are hyphens screwing up my duplicate finding conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet I use as a database of scientific papers.  I copy journal article titles from different sources (some could be from an email, others are links on a web page, or just the title from the article page).  I have conditional formatting set to let me know if I'm adding a title that is already in the list.  I've noticed that there are some titles that are "ignoring" the conditional formatting, and it looks like there are hyphens in all of the offenders.  If I remove the hyphens, the conditional formatting works.  So there is some 'difference' in the hyphens originating from the same title that is preventing the conditional formatting from viewing them as identical.

[Shared sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hxuOcvmeQTnvsncD5CqNjVMsRa9XXlU0hgEWUsi777s/edit?usp=sharing)

Examples of offending titles:

End-to-end continuous bioprocessing: impact on facility design, cost of goods and cost of development for monoclonal antibodies

End‐to‐end continuous bioprocessing: impact on facility design, cost of goods and cost of development for monoclonal antibodies

End‐to‐end continuous bioprocessing: Impact on facility design, cost of goods, and cost of development for monoclonal antibodies

What is this difference, and is there a way to fix it?  Do I need to write a script to find/replace the hyphens to get this to work?

TIA

Comment: Can you edit the post by giving exampls of titles that result in this problem?

Comment: The examples are in the shared sheet.  I added some to the post, but I don't think it will help any.  Here the SO code makes them all look the same.

Answer (score 2):

Just because characters appear identical, it does not mean that they are identical. You have fallen foul of the similarity between the hyphen and dashes. Visually, they are almost identical - dashes are slightly widest than the hyphen.

Dashes are regarded as "special characters" (i.e. they aren't keys on the keyboard) but they are used widely in html. So if, for instance, you copied an item from a website then you might unwittingly have copied dashes rather than hyphens.

You can identify the exact nature of a character by using the `CODE` function.

---

You ask *"What is this difference, and is there a way to fix it? Do I need to write a script to find/replace the hyphens to get this to work?"*

**WHAT IS THIS DIFFERENCE?**

It's important to recognise that though these examples appear identical, there are other differences that are more than just hyphens vs dashes.

- Example#1 - `Hyphen` - CODE returns "45"
- Example#2 - `Dash` - CODE returns "8208"
- Example#3 - `Dash` - CODE returns "8208".

  - But there are other factors that contribute to fail to trigger the conditional formatting rule:
  - Length = 128 (vs 127 for the other examples). There is an additional comma (after "cost of sales")
  - the word "Impact" is spelled with an upper case "I" (lower case for the other examples)

**MOVING FORWARD**

*Do you need a script?* No (IMHO)

*Is there a way to fix it?* As outlined above, there are more differences that just hyphens and dashes. And, as time goes by, the number & type of difference might increase. However, there is a solution to the "Hyphen Vs Dash" problem which is the focus of this question.

**FORMULA AND FORMATTING**

Your data is currently in Column A and Column A is also subject to conditional formatting.

- Remove the conditional formatting rules from Column A
- Insert this formula in cell B2

`=arrayformula(if(LEN($A2:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2:A, char(8208), ""))=0,A2:A,arrayformula(substitute(A2:A,char(8208),char(45)))))`

- Conditional Formatting for Column B

  - select the range in Column B
  - select, Format, Conditional Formatting.
  - Select "Custom Formula is" and enter this formula: `=countif($B$2:$B2,B2)>1`
  - Select a preferred Formatting Style and then click Done.

---

**FORMULA LOGIC**

- `arrayformula` enables the formula to automatically populate all the relevant cell in the column.
- `LEN($A2:A)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2:A, char(8208), ""))=0`

  - a test for dashes in a string. It substitutes a nil value for any/all instances of a dash (char(8208)), then compares the length to the adjusted length. If the value is zero, then there are no dashes in the string.
- `IF`: Test for any dashes,

  - if the string doesn't contain any dashes then use that value
  - else, the string must contains dashes so substitute any dashes for hyphens, and use the substituted value

    - `arrayformula(substitute(A2:A,char(8208),char(45)))`

The conditional formatting rule then looks for duplicate values in the column, and formats any/all duplicate values.

You'll note that Example#3 is not flagged as a duplicate despite containing dashes. This is because of the spelling of "Impact" and the extra comma after "cost of sales".

---

**Sample**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.  Your explanation for the third example doesn't make sense, though.  If I change the case of the 'I', it still doesn't trigger.  So something else is stopping that one if it isn't the hyphens/dashes.  The question still stands:  Is there a way to fix this?  Could I write a script to search for dashes and replace them with hyphens?

Comment: I've restructured my answer and I've also added a solution to detect and adjust dashes.

Comment: "Your explanation for the third example doesn't make sense, though. If I change the case of the 'I', it still doesn't trigger." True. I didn't do enough work on that. Example#3 has a length of 128 Characters (compared to 127 for the others); the difference is a coma after the words "Cost of sales".